# Switching 2 Activities on single touch i.e.- using setOnLongClickListener and onTouch ACTION_UP

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-listview, onclick

So suppose I want to switch between 2 activities using a single long click, I would, 
1) Use a long press > 1 sec on a button on the first activity to get to the second activity 
We can achieve this step by using setOnLongClickListener .

The problem comes in when I get to the 2nd activity
2) I would continue the long press onto the second activity which is a ListView
3) The second activity is a ListView with a list of options that can be selected
4) At this point I would continue the long press and move my finger over the option in the ListView I want to select.
5) Now I will release my finger and I want the ListItem on which I have released my finger on to be selected and this will also move the second activity to the 3rd activity

I have searched far and wide but couldn't find a way to solve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated